# Transcoding Video to QuickTime Animation (RLE)

Tags: video-conversion, quicktime, transcode, camstudio

I need to transcode video created using the Camstudio Lossless Codec into the QuickTime RLE format in order to get it to work with some other software.

What methods can I use to convert the video? I seem to have trouble finding software that will encode my video like this.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -c:v qtrle output.mov
```

That will copy any audio, subtitle, or other non-video streams, and transcode video with the specified video codec.  For supported options specific to qtrle,
`ffmpeg -h encoder=qtrle`

Comment: What about the other way? I have FFMPEG and I try copy a MOV file which is encoded in `qtrle` and I get: `Could not find tag for codec qtrle in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container`.

Comment: If this works, the `-codec copy` parameter (which copies a stream without re-encoding it) is, I believe, overridden by the `-c:v qtrle` parameter, which re-encodes the stream (is lossy). In other words the `-codec copy` parameter does nothing and can be removed.

Comment: @r_alex_hall: `-c copy` applies to audio and subtitle streams, too.  So it's like `-c:a copy -c:s copy -c:v qtrle`  The ffmpeg man page uses this as an example: `ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0 -c copy -c:v:1 libx264 -c:a:137 libvorbis OUTPUT` will copy all streams (`-map 0`), except transcode the 2nd video and the 138th audio.  The default for most containers is not `copy` for audio, it's some specific codec.